# Output content of WordPress Shortcode in text and footer

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a custom WordPress shortcode to add a modal to my content.
The content of the modal is based on a Custom Post Type.

The shortcode looks like this:

```
[term value="Custom Link Title" id="123"]
```

The `value=""` argument is for the modal link in the content. The `id=""` is the ID of the Custom Post Type.

Inside the modal dialog window I display the content from the Custom Post Type based on it's ID.

The problem is, that the link and the modal dialog are outputted togehter.
And because of the `<div>` of the modal, WordPress closes every `<p>` before it. And now there is a unwanted line break after the modal link.

**Is there any way to display the modal link in the content area and put the modal dialog (the `<div>`) in the footer of the page?**

Here's my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('btn', 'bs_button');

// [term value="" id=""]
function shortcode_term($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id' => '',
      'value' => '',
   ), $atts));


$modal_term = '<a href="#termModal_'.$id.'" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termModal_'.$id.'">'.$value.'</a>';

$modal_dialog = '<div class="modal fade" id="termModal_'.$id.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termModal_'.$id.'_Title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="termModal_'.$id.'_Title">'.get_the_title($id).'</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                '.get_post_field('post_content', $id).'
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';

return $modal_term.$modal_dialog;

}

add_shortcode('term', 'shortcode_term');
```

It would be nice if `$modal_term` stays in the content and `$modal_dialog` goes to the footer of the page.

Or is there any other way to prevent WordPress from adding a `</p>` before the modal dialog?

Here's whats happening in the frontend:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">noraml text from the editor <a href="#termModal_123" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termModal_123">Custom Link Title</a></p>
<div class="modal fade" id="termModal_123" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termModal_123_Title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="termModal_123_Title">Term Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Head</h2>
                Term Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Rest of the normal Text from the editor
```

The `</p>` after the `<a href="">..</a>` souldn't be there.

Comment: It is probably not WP itself adding that closing `</p>` tag - but the error correction of the browser. And no, there is no _easy_ way to have this short code put out part of its content somewhere else, that is not how shortcode rendering is implemented.

Comment: Can you tell me which version are you using it?

Comment: WordPress 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `wp_footer` from your shortcode function to return the modal dialog markup at the end of the document.

```
function shortcode_term($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id' => '',
      'value' => '',
   ), $atts));

$modal_term = '<a href="#termModal_'.$id.'" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termModal_'.$id.'">'.$value.'</a>';
$modal_dialog = '<div class="modal fade" id="termModal_'.$id.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termModal_'.$id.'_Title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="termModal_'.$id.'_Title">'.get_the_title($id).'</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                '.get_post_field('post_content', $id).'
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() use ( $modal_dialog ) {
  echo $modal_dialog;
} );
return $modal_term;
}

add_shortcode('term', 'shortcode_term');
```