# WordPress: Get all shortcodes from content field

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a custom shortcode to display a Bootstrap Modal inside my content. The problem is, that the `<div>` breaks the content. See here: [Output content of WordPress Shortcode in text and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594509/output-content-of-wordpress-shortcode-in-text-and-footer)

No2 I want to change the shortcode and display only the link of the Modal and display the modal-`<div>` after the content.

To do so, I check if the content field has shortcodes and if that's the case, I display all modals after the content.

Here's the code for that: 
(Part from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196564/1788961)

```
$content = get_sub_field("textfield");
//write the begining of the shortcode
$shortcode = 'term';

$check = strpos($content,$shortcode);
if($check=== false) {
    //echo '<h1>NO Shortcode</h1>';
} else {
    //echo '<h1>HAS Shortcode</h1>';


    $str = '[term value="Term Name" id="600"][term value="Another Term" id="609"]';

    preg_match_all('~\[term value="(.+?)" id="(.+?)"]~', $str, $matches);

    var_dump($matches[2]);

    foreach($matches[2] as $match){
        echo 
            '<div class="modal fade" id="termModal_'.$match.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="termModal_'.$match.'_Title" aria-hidden="true">
                (rest of modal)
            </div>
        ';


    }


}
```

Everything works fine so far. But now I need the shortcodes from the content field.

I don't know how to get them. Here's my Shortcode:

```
[term value="Custom Link Title" id="123"]
```

I need the id from every Shortcode inside the content and store them in the `$str' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method using the `preg_match()` function should work:

```
$id = 0;
$matches = array();
preg_match('#\[term(.*) id="([0-9]{1,})"(.*)\]#', $content, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 2) {
    $id = $matches[2];
}
```

That will work irrespective of the order the shortcode attribures are in but it assumes that you have double quotes around the `id` attribute value and that the value consists of only digits.

Comment: You get `0` for `$id`? If so, are you sure `$content` contains the shortcode?

Comment: I had to use the custom filed like this: `get_sub_field("textfield", false, false);` otherwise the shortcode isn't in the content as code. Now it works. Thanks!